# How to keep three decimals for prices, while showing two decimals on the frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have a Variable Product with a very small price (0.023€).
As shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbD7X.jpg

I have set the minimum quantity amount to 1000.

The correct price when someone selects a quantity of 1000 should be:

0.023€ * 1000 = 23€

But my Currency Switcher (Aelia) calculates it wrong. Because i have set the decimals to 2, it only takes the first 2 decimals into the calculation.
It displays 20€ instead of 23€. (0.02 * 1000 = 20€)

Only if i change the decimals in the settings from 2 to 3. It calculates it correctly and displays the correct price (23€)

But unfortunately, it then looks like this: 23.000€
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXjxu.jpg

With 3 decimals it shows the correct price, but i dont want it to have 3 decimals displayed. I want to display only 2 decimals, like this: 23.00€

I already tried a couple of filters, but none seem to work for me:

```
//Test 1
    add_filter('wc_price_args', function($args) {
      // Always format prices with two decinmals
      $args['decimals'] = 2;
      return $args;
    }, 10);

//Test 2
    add_filter('wc_price_args', 'custom_decimals_price_args', 10, 1);
    function custom_decimals_price_args($price, $args) {
      
      return number_format((float)$price, 2, '.', '');
    
    }

//Test 3
    add_filter( 'wc_get_price_decimals', 'change_prices_decimals', 20, 1 );
    function change_prices_decimals( $decimals ){
    $decimals = 2;
    return $decimals;
    }
```

I also tried this solution, that the currency switcher plugin provides for rounding Taxes, but doesnt work either:
https://aelia.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/3000038344-aelia-currency-switcher-how-to-implement-custom-rounding-of-converted-prices

Any ideas how i could fix this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How comfortable are you with editing templates? You only want to change the front-end value but keep it the same on the back-end.

Comment: I have just a little bit of programming experience, so not that comfortable. Yes, i was thinking about keeping the decimal value to 3 in the backend, and only change what is shown in the frontend to 2 decimals.

Comment: It will be difficult to help you at this point without more details just because there are so many different ways the price might be displaying in WordPress. What theme are you using?

Comment: "WooCommerce > Settings" has some currency options where you can set the number of decimal points to be displayed in the price.

Comment: @Ojav I already tried to set the value within WooCommerce Settings to 2 and the value within my Currency Switcher Plugin to 3.
Unfortunately, they are linked to each other. So if i change the value of WooCommerce decimals settings, it also changes the other one as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add conditions for frontend / backend with the function is_admin() like so:

```
add_filter('wc_price_args', 'BN_filter_price_decimals');

        function BN_filter_price_decimals($args) {
        
        //Backend = 3
        if (is_admin()) {  $args['decimals'] = 3; 
        }
        // Frontend = 2
        else { $args['decimals'] = 2; }
        }

        return $args;
    }
```